# Why does my Sails.js app have a route I never added

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have created a new Sails app, and so far I have created an api using `sails generate api guitar`, and then added this code in the controller:

```
module.exports = {    
    fender: function(req, res){  
        console.log(req.params);
        res.notFound();  
    }
};
```

As expected, when I go to `http://localhost:1337/guitar/fender` I get a `404 error` (that's the response I programed). But what I don't get is, if I go to `http://localhost:1337/guitar/fender/4`, the console will show `[ id: '4' ]`. I seems that somewhere there's a `GET /guitar/fender/:id` (using Express/Rails syntax here) sort of URL. But I don't see it anywhere, not in `config/routes.js` or anywhere else.

So, does Sails.js create a `:id` for every controller action automatically? Or am I missing something here?

I tried some things, such as adding this to the `config/routes.js` file:

`'get /guitar/fender/:brand': 'GuitarController.fender'`

And then when I go to the URL again, `[ brand: '4' ]` will be printed instead of `id`.

**So my final question is: Does Sails.js automatically make an `:id` for every controller action?**

(I couldn't find this on the docs either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up REST development, Sails uses an internal API called **Blueprint**.

When you run the "generate" command, Sails creates for you all CRUD operations to handle your entity, so you can immediately test your API without any code.

Here you created a guitar entity. Now you can play with it directly in your web browser! Let's try this on localhost:

1. `/guitar/create?name=Ibanez`
2. `/guitar`
3. `/guitar/4`
4. `/guitar/update/4?name=Stratocaster`
5. `/guitar/4`
6. `/guitar/destroy/4`
7. `/guitar`

If you want more information about Blueprint, you can:

- Read [this section](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) from Sails documentation
- Take a look at the **config/blueprints.js** file in your Sails project